# Building a smaller python extra package

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have a package called mypygeopack, which has lots of dependencies.  I wanted to know if I can create a small package using extras:

`pip install mypygeopack[tiny]`

which will install a stripped down version of the package with only 1-2 dependencies instead of the 4-5.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, `mypygeopack[tiny]` would install _extra_ dependencies. I don't think you can prevent installation of the base dependencies with extras like `[tiny]`.

Comment: You could upload a new version of your package to PyPI, with the `_tiny` suffix to whatever your package name is. This will probably make your code a bit harder to maintain though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Extras can only add things, not remove.

It is a question that comes up regularly. People have discussed about it, but as far as I know, nothing concrete came out of those discussions yet:

- https://discuss.python.org/t/is-it-valid-to-specify-extra-negative-dependency-with-pep508-markers/5277
- https://discuss.python.org/t/the-extra-environment-marker-and-its-operators/4976
- https://discuss.python.org/t/adding-a-default-extra-require-environment/4898

Answer (score 0):

possibly this would work:

```
pip install --no-deps <package>
pip install -r minimal_requirements.txt // this has the minimal requirements not all.
```